# Customize Legend in Apache Superset deck.gl Scatter Plot

Tags: scatter-plot, apache-superset, deck.gl

I want to add the contribution to each legend as shown in the below Apache Superset deck.gl scatter plot ( For e.g. Excellent(4,5) should be `Excellent(4,5) 1406 88.19%`
where  Excellent(4,5) = Categorical Color
1406 = # of Events and 88.19% = % out of total Events.
Is this possible to show in legend ?
[image]